# how to bind helm-do-grep-1 to a key in emacs?

Tags: emacs, emacs-helm

I am using the following.

```
(global-set-key [f9] 'helm-do-grep-1)
```

But when I press f9, It complains wrong type argument. I just want it behavior like "C-u C-c h g" to grep recursively.  But type so many keys is boring.

update:
I need to grep recursively. helm-do-grep run in non-recursive mode.

Comment: Are you sure you want `'helm-do-grep1` and not `'helm-do-grep`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
(global-set-key [f9] 
  (lambda ()
    (interactive)
    (let ((current-prefix-arg 't))
      (call-interactively 'helm-do-grep))))
```

Upd. If you're interested: the version with kbd sequence

```
(global-set-key [f9]
  (lambda ()
   (interactive)
     (let ((minibuffer-message-timeout 0))
                (execute-kbd-macro (read-kbd-macro "C-u C-c h g C-x Q"))))
```

See the definition of <kbd>C-x Q</kbd> here https://stackoverflow.com/a/28435402/1937596

Comment: The code doesn't throw any error. but after executed it, press f9, there is reponse.

Answer (score 1):

As the error message already points out, the function `helm-do-grep-1` has one argument: https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/blob/master/helm-grep.el#L810

Probably what you wanted is binding `f9` to `helm-do-grep` which calls `helm-do-grep-1` in return with the correct parameters (
https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/blob/master/helm-grep.el#L1129)

```lisp
(global-set-key [f9] 'helm-do-grep)
```

**Update:**

- You can find several solutions to your question here: http://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/2dxj69/how_do_make_helmdogrep_to_do_recursive_always/
- To show another possibility you could also do the following:

```lisp
(global-set-key [f5]
                (lambda ()
                  (interactive)
                  (call-interactively (key-binding (kbd "C-c h g")))))
```

In that case, you call `helm-do-grep` using `<f5>` and the recursive approach with `C-u <f5>`. However, this approach will depend on your key bindings.

Comment: I need to grep recursively. helm-do-grep run in non-recursive mode

Comment: I see now. This was not immediately clear from your first formulation. I will update my answer with a hopefully useful link